# Remote temperature sensor system without slave board

Tags: wireless

I want to build a temperature control network over my house reading data from each room and sending it to the main board for further processing. I need about 6 sensor nodes sending the data over the air to the main node.
There are tons of tutorials of making master-slave temperature/pressure etc control systems of 2 Arduino boards communicating via wireless channel.
I find it a bit expensive to have a board per sensor node. **Is that possible to build a sensor device without a controller using just a sensor, a battery and a wireless transmitter plus required radio components?** It's ok to send raw data to the main node. Assuming it knows the protocol it will be able to decode the data there from all the incoming channels.

Comment: Only if the wireless transmitter itself is a control board. Like the ESP8266.

Answer (score 1):

As @Majenko said on comment, its possible. One of the choice is ESP8266. Your project has been successfully accomplished, you can check [here](https://github.com/astoklas/ESP8266-Temperature-Sensor), [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Low-cost-WIFI-temperature-data-logger-based-on-ESP/), or [here](https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/2519/temperature-sensor-on-esp8266/10). NSP8266 only needs 3-3.6V (low current) supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

@Sergey if its cost what's bothering you , there are numerous low-cost options for MCUs. For eg you can club a MSP 430 ( probably <1$) chip with a cheap RF transmitter which wont burn a hole in your pocket and is absolutely reliable. Wifi modules can be a little expensive and need constant connectivity. So, you have a choice on this.